# Virtualbox dynamically-allocated disk *.vdi keeps growing

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

When using Linux in Virtualbox and dynamically-allocated disk, it keeps growing even though almost half of space is free:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        94G   12G   78G  13% /
```

This disk takes >24G on disk and keeps growing, filesystem ext4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to discard unused blocks on filesystem there is a command `fstrim`, part of `util-linux` package.
But to use it on Virtualbox, it is needed to enable discard option on your virtual disk by stopping you VM and running the following command:

`VBoxManage storageattach <VM name> --storagectl "SATA" --port 0 --discard on`

where "SATA" and 0 are parameters of your disk controller, can be checked in VB settings for your specific VM.

Then boot your machine and run

`# fstrim /`

To automate this process, add this command to cron, once in a week is usually enough.